# What is $\gcd(\sigma(q^{k-1}), \sigma(q^k))$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, solution-verification, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma$ denote the classical sum-of-divisors function.

> What is $\gcd(\sigma(q^{k-1}), \sigma(q^k))$?

Update:  I have transferred the transcript of my attempt to an actual answer to this MSE question.  Thanks to mixedmath for pointing it out!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write out a comment and for informing me about the correctness of my solution, @JackD'Aurizio!  Appreciate it.  =)

Comment: Innovative and beautiful

Comment: Thanks @Anjan3!  I learned this method of proof via MSE.  I just wanted to make sure I applied it properly on the first time!  =)

Comment: Arnie, I encourage you to rewrite your question to be just the question. Then write your answer as an answer, accept it (because it's correct) and we can upvote you and be happy. If you're reputation concious, you can make your answer Community Wiki if you really want.

Comment: @mixedmath, ohh I didn't know that that is something permitted on this site =)  Will do!  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt at an answer:

$$\sigma(q^{k-1}) = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}$$
$$\sigma(q^k) = \frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1}$$

Therefore:

$$\gcd(\sigma(q^{k-1}),\sigma(q^k)) = {\left(\frac{1}{q - 1}\right)}\gcd(q^k - 1, q^{k+1} - 1) = \frac{q^{\gcd(k,k+1)} - 1}{q - 1} = 1.$$