# If $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, is it necessarily true that $\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(q^{(k-1)/2})\bigg)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma$ denote the classical sum-of-divisors function.  In what follows, we let $q$ be a prime number.

Here is my question:

> If $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, is it necessarily true that $\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(q^{(k-1)/2})\bigg)=1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I pattern my approach after the answer to this closely related [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1295549).

$$\sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}})=\frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 1}{q - 1}$$
$$\sigma(q^k)=\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1}$$

Therefore,
$$\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}),\sigma(q^k)\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{1}{q-1}\bigg)\gcd\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 1, q^{k+1} - 1\bigg)=\frac{q^{\gcd\bigg(\frac{k+1}{2}, \hspace{0.05in} k+1\bigg)} - 1}{q - 1}$$
$$=\frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 1}{q - 1} = \sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}).$$

But $\sigma(q^{(k-1)/2}) = 1$ is true if and only if
$$q^{(k-1)/2} = 1 \iff (k-1)/2 = 0 \iff k = 1.$$

> Is this proof correct?

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thank you for your feedback!  Could you write down your last comment as an actual answer, so that I would be able to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work shown here follows the same pattern as that of the closely related MSE question that was referenced. Based on that, plus my own checking, what you've shown in your proof attempt all looks fine to me.

One small thing to note is that since $q^{k + 1} - 1 = \left(q^{(k+1)/2} - 1\right)\left(q^{(k+1)/2} + 1\right)$, this is another way to see that $\gcd\left(q^{k + 1} - 1, q^{(k+1)/2} - 1\right) = q^{(k+1)/2} - 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @JohnOmielan!  Gladly accepting it now.